# Renaming an index in a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to rename the index of a series `libor` I have from DATE to Date:

```
libor.rename(index={"DATE": "Date"})
```

The result is unforunately the same as it went in though:

```
            VALUE
DATE    
1986-01-02  8.12500
1986-01-03  8.12500
1986-01-06  8.18750
```

I was hoping that 'DATE' would become 'Date'. I'm trying to multiply it with a Dataframe with a 'Date' index, on a column-by-column basis.

How can I rename the index?

Comment: Did you pass `inplace=True`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the name property of the index.

```
libor.index.name = 'Date'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [rename_axis()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for that:

Example:

```
In [310]: s
Out[310]:
Index
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [312]: s = s.rename_axis('idx')

In [313]: s
Out[313]:
idx
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```